# Flatten an array, i.e [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]] should give an output of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. The source of error in the code

Tags: javascript

```
function splitArray(array){

    let realArray = [array].reduce(a,b => {

       a.concat(b);

    });

}

console.log(splitArray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to

- return the reduced result,
- wrap the parameters (if more than one) of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),
- return the value of concat.

```js
function splitArray(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.concat(b);
    });
}

console.log(splitArray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]));
```

By using only one expression to return, you could omit curly brackets and the return statement.

```js
function splitArray(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
}

console.log(splitArray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been banging my head against the computer screen for last half an hour, just to find out there were these basic errors. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors, try:

```js
function splitArray(array){

   let realArray = array.reduce((a,b) => {
    return a.concat(b);
   });

  return realArray;
}

console.log(splitArray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code.

1. You need to return from the `splitArray` function
2. The accumulator need to be returned from reduce callback function
3. `[array]` in `[array].reduce` is wrong. It need to be `array.reduce`
4. The parameters inside array callback function need to be inside a brace like (a,b)

```js
function splitArray(array) {

  return array.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.concat(b);
  });

}

console.log(splitArray([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6]
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several things:

1. The `return` value from the `splitArray()` function.
2. Using of `return a.concat(b)`
3. Parenthesis around the multiple params `(a, b)`

```js
function splitArray(array) {
  let realArray = array.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.concat(b);
  }, []);
  return realArray;
}

console.log(splitArray([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6]
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply use `[].concat(...<array to flatten>)`

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]

console.log([].concat(...array)); //Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array) if speard syntax not supported
```